# How do I put a delay on an Alert Box made with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, delay, onload

I have an alert box that pops up if someone enters a website using Internet Explorer. The problem I am having is that the alert shows up instantly, so sometimes the previous website is still visible when the alert shows up. I need to put on a delay, so that the website can load up before the alert shows up - or make it only show once everything is loaded. I use Wordpress.

I have tried numerous pieces of code that I found online, but unfortunately none of them has worked for me, mainly because I dont know how to "include it" with the code I already have (which I got from a different Stack Overflow thread)

```
function isIE() {
  ua = navigator.userAgent;

  /* MSIE used to detect old browsers and Trident used to newer ones*/
  var is_ie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;

  return is_ie; 
}
/* Create an alert to show if the browser is IE or not */
if (isIE()){
    alert('MY ALERT MESSAGE');
}
```

I want the alert to show up after the page has been loaded, either in form of a delay or by using onload. Javascript "only" is prefered since I work with a webpage builder that does not like jQuery.

Comment: Use a `setTimeout`.

Comment: `so sometimes the previous website is still visible when the alert shows up` that doesn't seem possible given that the new URL has to send a response and the DOM built from it's response before the JS should run. It sounds like an IE bug if you're seeing that. As such I'd suggest placing your JS logic just before `</body>`

Comment: "I want the alert to show up after the page has been loaded," So call it on page load.....

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I am on Google and I enter the website with IE, the alert shows up but I am still seeing the Google website. Only after clicking "OK" do I see my website.

Comment: Good old IE... :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you statement in setTimeout. Time is in miliSeconds

```
if (isIE()){
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('MY ALERT MESSAGE');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding the script tag at the bottom of the page, or use the `onload` of the body element.

In both cases, the alert will come after the html has reached the user.

---

Another more elegant way could be to make a small modal yourself, i.e. create your own "alert". By default, you hide it, and show it when the user has IE:

```
// CSS
#browserWarning{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 25px;
}

// Javascript
if (isIE()){
    document.getElementById("browserWarning").style.display = 'block';
}
```

You can now crate something that looks a bit better, allows for a bit more explanation (I'm assuming "IE not supported because" messages here), and because it's non-blocking, the rest of your page keeps on loading.

Comment: I am not a pro with "raw code", but I tried copy-pasting the code you wrote but no alert shows up when using that. I don't know if it's supposed to or if your code is more of a helping hand but I actually need more? :)

Comment: No, it does not magically work, there is no browserwarning element, you must create it